# Как импортировать собственный модуль в Python 3.6.5?

Tags: python-3.x, импорт, python-3.6, модули

Имеется модуль launchcom, который находится по адресу: D:\nicole\modules\launchcom\launchcom.py
Основная программа находится по адресу: D:\nicole\nicole.py
Как импортировать модуль launchcom в nicole?
При необходимости код модуля и основной программы могу дать в комментариях.

Я создавал launchcom с целью получить возможность импортировать мини-приложения и мини-игры в nicole. К сожалению без launchcom обходиться будет трудно, т.к nicole слишком объёмный код для этой задачи. Т.к nicole становится всё больше, разработчикам становится всё труднее искать функцию com для прямого инсталлирования в nicole.

Сердечно прошу помочь с этой проблемой. Если вам потребуется код модуля - пишите, я приложу в комментариях. Если нужен код nicole - обращайтесь, постараюсь приложить в .py файле или скриншотах.

Comment: Читали про модули и пакеты? :) Еще есть способ через добавление `sys.path` пути к нужному модулю, вот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/815f1e9b8577f30c6b505a24ff9271addc5a9fd6/Check%20with%20notification/Check%20new%20video%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80/main.py#L16

Comment: @gil9red Т.е нужно прописать : import sys, и после этого: sys.path.append('адрес')?

Comment: Да, и тогда при импорте питон будет также в той папке искать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import modules.launchcom.launchcom as launchcom
```